# How to get an element by class name

Tags: java, html, jsoup

```
<td class="calendar_day" data-day-index="6">
  <div class="calendar_date">Mar. 1st</div>
  <div class="calendar_cell_content">
    <ul>
      <li class="">
```

I am trying to get the value from the `class="calendar_date"` (Mar. 1st).

I have all the html code that I'm trying to parse saved in a String variable named returned.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(returned);
Elements elem = doc.getElementsByClass("calendar_date");
String date = elem.first().text();
```

If I'm doing it like this the `date` String is `null`.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jsoup (1.7.3)?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should check whether the content of variable `returned` is the same as you describe above.

Then, you should try the latest version of [**`jsoup 1.7.3`**](http://jsoup.org/download). I have run the following code, it works.

```
    String returned
            = "<td class=\"calendar_day\" data-day-index=\"6\">\n"
            + "  <div class=\"calendar_date\">Mar. 1st</div>\n"
            + "  <div class=\"calendar_cell_content\">\n"
            + "    <ul>\n"
            + "      <li class=\"\">";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(returned);
    Elements elem = doc.getElementsByClass("calendar_date");
    String date = elem.first().text();
    System.out.println(date);
```

The result is what you expected: `Mar. 1st`